# Logical Schema Error Checking

Tags: database, schema, normalization, theory

So In the study guide for our final, the professor gave us this Information preserving logical design, Where bold is a primary key and italics are a foreign key.

- L1: Donor: **D_ID**, D_Name, *[0, L1, 1]D_Spouse[0, N, 1], [1, L5, 1]D_CI_ID[1, C, 1]*
- L2: Non-Alumni: ***[1, L1, 3]NA_D_ID[1, u]***, NA_Gender, NA_RelDesc
- L3: Alumni: **A_UID**, A_Gender, A_Schnum, *[1, L1, 3]A_D_ID[1, u]*
- L4: Business:***[1, L1, 3]Bus_D_ID[1, u]***, Bus_Contact, Bus_MatchAmt
- L5: Contact_Info: **CI_ID**, CI_Address
- L6: Phone: **Ph_Number**, ***[0, L5, n]Ph_CI_ID[1, C, 1]***
- L7: Email: **EM_Address**, ***[0, L5, n]EM_CI_ID[1, C, 1]***

The problem that he wants us to solve is to  List any undesirable FD’s that need to be addressed through decomposition, and which normal form they violate.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical schema form checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396518/logical-schema-form-checking)

Comment: Rather than asking the same question repeatedly, you should [edit] your original question to be more focused and more answerable. That might get it more attention.